# How to mock a function using typescript in jest using jest.fn()

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to mock a function named callApi.  I use jest.fn(), but I am having the error message:

> function callApi(method: string, url: string, path: string, data?: any): Promise>
>   Cannot assign to 'callApi' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

I have tried to follow the examples on 
[jest examples](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c)

What is wrong with my code?  Why am I having the error message.
Part of callApi is
    import axios from "axios";

```
export function callApi(
  method: string,
  url: string,
  path: string,
  data?: any
) {
  switch (method) {
```

The test is as follows:

```
import {runSaga} from 'redux-saga';
import * as api from '../Utilities/api'
import { getPaymentsError, getPaymentsSuccess, IPaymentsAction } from './actions';
import handleFetch from './sagas'


test('should test fetch payments success',async() =>{
const dispatchedActions = [{}];
const mockedPayments = [{
    details: {
    amount: "10000",
    date: new Date(),
    id: 5
  },
  id: 5,
  month: "Feb 2003",
  userID: 3
}];


 api.callApi = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockedPayments));<----------error here



const fakeStore = {
    dispatch:(action:IPaymentsAction) =>dispatchedActions.push(action)
}
await runSaga(fakeStore,handleFetch).done;
expect(api.callApi.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
expect(dispatchedActions).toContainEqual(getPaymentsSuccess(mockedPayments));
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning to a `jest.fn()` doesn't work well with TypeScript typing.

Use `jest.spyOn` instead:

```ts
test('should test fetch payments success', async (done) => {
  const dispatchedActions = [{}];
  const mockedPayments = [{
    details: {
      amount: "10000",
      date: new Date(),
      id: 5
    },
    id: 5,
    month: "Feb 2003",
    userID: 3
  }];

  const spy = jest.spyOn(api, 'callApi');
  spy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockedPayments));

  const fakeStore = {
    dispatch: (action: IPaymentsAction) => dispatchedActions.push(action)
  }
  await runSaga(fakeStore, handleFetch);done();
  expect(spy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  expect(dispatchedActions).toContainEqual(getPaymentsSuccess(mockedPayments));
})
```

Comment: I am having the error     Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

      at pTimeout (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:53:21)
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:523:19)

Comment: @jupitersailormoon that is a separate issue (sounds like your saga might not be resolving) and should be addressed in a new question if help is needed.

Comment: I have added the done function .  Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603939/async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-the-5000ms-timeout-specified-by-jest-setti and thanks @brian-lives-outdoors

Comment: After hours of searching, this answer saved me from slamming my keyboard off my desk. THANK YOU!