# how should i fix jest integration test errors causing due to timeout?

Tags: npm, jestjs, integration-testing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, supertest

I'm getting inconsistent results when every I run `npm test`

Sometimes all test pass and most of the time one or the other test fails due to this error:

```sh
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:68:21
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:678:19)
```

I have noticed when ever test files name is printed twice or thrice some test fails.

I'm using WSL to run the tests and I have configured `jestjs` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose --coverage"
},
"jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
},
```

how should I configure jest so the tests run properly or fix this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603939/async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-the-5000ms-timeout-specified-by-jest-setti)

Comment: in case you don't use unmocked timeouts, may you provide sample test that is failing? do your question's tags mean that tests always passes at Linux(say, at CI server)?

Comment: Provide the code you want to test.