# How to call an Async function from an Async function?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, async-await, jestjs

I have this Jest test that calls an async function called `getLD` which is itself an async function:

```
test("Should generate correct lexical density", async () => {
    var ld = await getLD("John is a Smith")
    console.log(ld);
    expect(ld).toEqual('Paul');
    expect.assertions(1);
})
```

And this is the async function it calls:

```
const NonLexWord = require('../models/Word');
exports.getLD = async (sentence) => {
    const nonLexicalWords = await NonLexWord.find({});
    // console.log(nonLexicalWords);
    const words = sentence.split(" ");
    const totalNumberOfWords = words.length;
    let totalNumberOfLexicalWords = 0;
    words.forEach(word => {
        const found = nonLexicalWords.find(element => element.name === word);
        if(!found) {
            totalNumberOfLexicalWords++;
        }
    });
    return parseFloat((totalNumberOfLexicalWords / totalNumberOfWords).toFixed(2));
}
```

My issue is that the body of the test never runs and I receive this error:

> : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms
>   timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not
>   invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

This is the Word model:

```
// For non lexical words
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const WordSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    }
});

module.exports = Word = mongoose.model('word', WordSchema);
```

Of Course I did try increasing the time threshold like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603939/async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-the-5000ms-timeout-specified-by-jest-setti).

Comment: How is `NonLexWord.find()` defined?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I just edited the question with the definition. It's a mongoose Schema model.

Comment: There is no mystery about this when the Async routine is called it is synchronous for that instant in that each line is processed one after the other.   If it encounters another asynchronous call then you are just adding the call.

Comment: Are you sure the function you are calling is finishing before the timeout? Does it just run longer than 5000ms?

Comment: @JaredSmith This function is used for an endpoint and it takes far less than 5000ms even though it runs several times. So yes.

Comment: only for testing purpose give more time to jest , put this row
jest.setTimeout(60000)
at the beginning of the test.

Comment: Unit test or integration test? Do your test cases depend on a real MongoDB server?