# Testing event emitters with Jest gives an error: Timeout-Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

This is my sample function and I want to create a test for it using jest, the S3 library test is already working but the "on" event listener gives an error

```js
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import * as csvParse from 'fast-csv';

async function downloadCsvFile(fileName: string, bucketName: string): Promise<any> {
  let parseStreamData;
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
  };
  try {
    await new S3().headObject(params).promise();
    let csvReadStream = new S3().getObject(params).createReadStream();
    let csvFileArray: Array<any> = [];
    parseStreamData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      csvParse
        .parseStream(csvReadStream, { headers: true })
        .on('data', function(data) {
          csvFileArray.push(data);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
          resolve(csvFileArray);
        })
        .on('error', function() {
          reject('csv parse process failed');
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  }
  return await parseStreamData;
}
```

This is my test, I already mocked the parseStream function with the "on" event listeners, but when I run the test it gives me an error

```js
import { bucketHandler } from './bucketHandler';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { parseStream } from "fast-csv";
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
jest.mock('aws-sdk');
jest.mock("fast-csv");

describe('handler', () => {
    test('downloadCsvFile', async () => {
        mocked(S3).mockImplementationOnce((): any => ({
            headObject: () => ({
                promise: () => Promise.resolve(),
          }),
        }));
        mocked(S3).mockImplementationOnce((): any => {
            return {
                getObject: () => {
                    return {
                        createReadStream: () => {
                            return {}
                        },
                    };
                },
            };
        });
        mocked(parseStream).mockImplementationOnce((): any => {                
           return {
                on: () => {
                    return {
                        on: () => {
                            return {
                                on: () => {
                                    return {}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
        expect(await bucketHandler.downloadCsvFile('1', '1')).toEqual([{}]);
      });
});
```

This is the error when I run the test:

```js
$ npm run test src/aws-s3/bucketHandler.test.ts

 FAIL  src/aws-s3/bucketHandler.test.ts (6.221s)
  handler
    × downloadCsvFile (5015ms)

  ● handler › downloadCsvFile

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

       8 |
       9 | describe('handler', () => {
    > 10 |     test('downloadCsvFile', async () => {
         |     ^
      11 |         mocked(S3).mockImplementationOnce((): any => ({
      12 |             headObject: () => ({
      13 |                 promise: () => Promise.resolve(),

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (src/aws-s3/bucketHandler.test.ts:10:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/aws-s3/bucketHandler.test.ts:9:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                   
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                   
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.77s, estimated 13s
Ran all test suites matching /src\\aws-s3\\bucketHandler.test.ts/i.
```

Comment: Did you try to add before 'describe' or inside 'test' `jest.useFakeTimers()` or `jest.useFakeTimes('modern')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603939/message-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-the-5000-ms-timeout-specified-by

Comment: Yes, I already try to add it but it still gives the same error, I think this node library was not properly mocked: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-data