# Why is JEST throwing a timeout on an async callback while using a different syntax?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am working with Jest in Node.js for learning purpose.

I am having some trouble after finding a first fix when my test failed with a timeout after 5000ms.

Strangely, my code works with the below syntax:

```
// This works
test('It should respond with 200 success', async () => {
    const response = await request(App).get('/launches'); 
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
});
```

However, it doesn't work for with an alternative syntax, that is normally used in test cases:

```
// This does not work
test('It should respond with 200 success', async () => {
    const response = await request(App)
        .get('/launches')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/) 
        .expect(200);
});
```

**What I tried so far**

I tried configuring my tests as follow:

```
// jest config file
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "node",
};

// Mongoose DB connection config modification in server.js file
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
```

The configuration fix mentioned above worked out for the first test case, but the second one is still failing. Here is the error that is thrown by the test suite for my second test case:

```
    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout
- Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

describe('Test GET/ launches', () => {
    test('It should respond with 200 success', async () => {
    ^
        const response = await request(App)
            .get('/launches')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
```

**Version Specs:**

Node: 12.19.0

Jest: 26.6.3

supertest: 6.1.3

mongoose: 6.3.8

Comment: Why would you change your syntax ? The first solution works perfectly fine _and_ you could still test your content type (on a side note, `/json/` would * not be a [standard HTML Content Type, semantic-wise](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.content-type).

Maybe chaining the `expect()` calls makes your treatment effectively slower by a few, needed miliseconds ? What is your `/launches` call doing ?

Comment: Also, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603939/message-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-the-5000-ms-timeout-specified-by?rq=2

Comment: @YassineBadache As I said in the Question I am still learning. So, I am finding a Syntax and a way that is more familiar with real-world projects. I have found the solution. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, after some trial and error, I found the solution by just increasing the timeout of the test function. In my case setting it to 6000ms sort out the problem. The probable cause here is the slower connection with MongoDB Atlas. Timeout always be changed. Writing it here so that it will help others who face similar issues.

```
test('It should respond with 200 success', async () => {
    const response = await request(App)
        .get('/launches')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/) 
        .expect(200);
}, 6000);
```

However, a better way is to have a separate DB connection script that can be connected and disconnected at multiple places. That would rectify this issue as well.

Comment: As you're learning, do not forget that sometimes (not always), response time is important, and the `timeout` could be part of the test process. Maybe you do want your request to respond in less than 5s / 6s / whatever, in that case the problem lies elsewhere !

Good job nontheless on finding a fix to your problem !